# Retrieve URL of image within node type

Tags: 7, media

I have two content types:

post_image_on_right

post_image_wide

post_image_on_right has three different image fields and each image field has it's own image style.

What I would like to do is depending on what node type, image field and image style is being displayed give me the image full path within the node to push into pinterest link attribute.

I thought a switch would have worked but the switch is looking for a change in node type. I need to check for node type image field and image style and pass those values.

```
switch ($node->type) {
case 'post_image_on_right':
$image_field = 'field_image_right';
$image_style = 'medium';
break; 

case 'post_image_on_right':
$image_field = 'field_image_vertical';
$image_style = 'medium_vertical';
break;

case 'post_image_on_right':
$image_field = 'field_image_tall';
$image_style = 'medium_tall';
break;

case 'post_wide_image':
$image_field = 'field_image_wide';
$image_style = 'large';
break; 
}

$field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, $image_field);

<a class="addthis_button_pinterest" pi:pinit:url="<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $node_url ?>" pi:pinit:media="<?php print image_style_url($image_style, $field_items[0]['uri']); ?>" pi:pinit:layout="horizontal"></a>
```

Comment: I can't understand your question, even I can't read your code, how you have three `post_image_on_right` in your switch statement?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry if this is confusing. I really only have two post types(content types) that I am looking out for. The one content type post_image_on_right has three different image field names and each field name has it's own image style attached to it. So I am looking for a way to check for content type && image field name && image style name and then pass those values to the pinterest attributes. Does that make sense?